# How to compile and run .cpp files after writing them in sublime text?

Tags: c++, netbeans, sublimetext2

I really prefer writing code in sublime text or anything else. So, naturally that's what I want to use. However, when I try to open the file in Netbeans, I get an error. So, I want to know how I can save a .cpp file from sublime text and then go about running it through the command prompt. I know I have to set up a path or something, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. Thanks for any help at all. Also, I am new to C++ and programming in general(have dabbled in Python a bit).

EDIT: Really sorry, I meant how do I actually execute/run the file afterwards. Like if the program were to just print out "Hello World".

Comment: Ctrl-B in Sublime Text should already work (except maybe not in ST2 then, idk).

Comment: What error do you get in Netbeans? What operating system are you using? What compiler?

Comment: @chris - yeah, it's `ctrl+b` in ST2 and 3...

Comment: ctrl+b is a command line shortcut. Make sure you can compile via command line first, aka `g++ -o a a.cpp`

Comment: @Cameron
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)

This is is the error I get in Netbeans when I try to import .cpp files to it.

I'm using Windows 8. And I meant run not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following build system should suit your needs, assuming that you're using the GNU Compiler Collection and `g++` for compiling your `.cpp` files:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["${file_base_name}"]
        }
    ]
}
```

*Please note that the following instructions are for Sublime Text 2 only...*

To use it, select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open the `Packages` folder in Windows Explorer. It should be located in `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2`. Or not, depending on your install. In either case, browse to the `C++` directory and open the file `C++.sublime-build` in Sublime and set the syntax to `JSON` if you want it to look prettier. Replace its entire contents with the code above, then save the file. The old code is kind of convoluted, and also runs some commands needlessly.

Now, set the build system by going to **`Tools -> Build System`** and selecting **`Automatic`**. Assuming that `g++` is in your `PATH`, you can build your executable using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> keyboard shortcut, also available via **`Tools -> Build`**. If your binary has already been compiled, you can run it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

One final note: if your program asks for any kind of input, or has a graphical user interface, this `Run` command won't work. Instead, replace it with the following:

```json
"name": "Run",
"cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"shell": true
```

This will open a new instance of the command line and run your program from there, instead of inside Sublime. The `/k` switch means that the window will be kept open after your program has run, so you can examine output, errors, etc. If instead you want the window to close immediately, simply change the `/k` to `/c`.

Good luck!